# Implementation of Bayes posterior predictive check

Tags: p-value, posterior, bayes

I have a question concerning the implementation of a bayes posterior
predictive check. Let us assume i have this model (implementation is
in R and jags):

```
model {
  for( i in 1 : N ) {
     y[i] ~ dlnorm( mu , 1/sig^2 )
   }
 sig ~ dunif( 0.01 , 1000 )
 mu ~ dnorm( 0,1E-6 )
}
```

I want to estimate the parameters of a lognormal distribution given
some data $y$. For the both parameters of the lognormal i use an
uninformative prior distribution. I carry out the mcmc sampling using
(code is form the book "Doing bayesian data analysis"):

```
parameters = c("mu" , "sig")
adaptSteps = 1000              
burnInSteps = 1000            
nChains = 3                   
numSavedSteps=30000 
thinSteps=1                  
nPerChain = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains ) 

# Create, initialize, and adapt the model:
jagsModel = jags.model( "model.txt" , data=datalist ,
                    n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
# Burn-in:
cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )
# The saved MCMC chain:
cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
codaSamples = coda.samples( jagsModel , variable.names=parameters ,
                        n.iter=nPerChain , thin=thinSteps )
mcmcChain = as.matrix( codaSamples )
chainLength = NROW(mcmcChain)

mu <- mcmcChain[, "mu"]
sig <-  mcmcChain[, "sig"]
L <- length(mu)
```

Now i want to check, how exact my model fits the dataset. According to
Gleman (2003, P.162), i have $L$ simulations from the posterior density of the
parameters mu and sig. For each of the $L$ parameters i simulated a new dataset
and calculate the test statistic with this new dataset and the original dataset and compare the results.
My algorithm looks like this:

```
result <- numeric(L)
for(i int 1:L) {
  yrep <- rlnorm(length(y),mu[i],sig[i])
  result[i] <- t(log(yrep),mu[i]) >= t(log(y),mu[i])
}
```

The function $t$ is the test statistic and checks if the model is adequate except for the extreme tails. It is defined like this:

$$T(y,m) = |y_{x_1} - m | - |y_{x_2} - m|$$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are chosen to represent approximately 90 and 10
percent of the distribution (see Gelman 2003, P.165).

Is this the right approach? If yes, would it be enough to use the
parameter values in the highest density interval only? I am fairly new to
bayesian statistics so i am unsure if i understood the whole procedure.
And is there a better test statistic? I know that my data will be approximately
lognormal. But at least in the lower tails there will be a lot of noise (the data are diameter distributions of particles recorded continuously by an optical sensor with limited resolution). In future the algorithm should run from time to time during the recording and send a notification when there is a huge deviation from the lognormal model.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the complete source

```
modelstring = "
model {
  for( i in 1 : N ) {
    y[i] ~ dlnorm( mu , 1/sig^2 )

  }
  sig ~ dunif( 0.01 , 1000 )
  mu ~ dnorm( 0,1E-6 )
}
" # close quote for modelstring
writeLines(modelstring,con="model.txt")


y <- rlnorm(1000,5,2)

datalist <- list(
    y = y,
    N = length(y))

parameters = c("mu" , "sig")
adaptSteps = 1000              # Number of steps to "tune" the samplers.
burnInSteps = 1000            # Number of steps to "burn-in" the samplers.
nChains = 3                   # Number of chains to run.
numSavedSteps=30000           # Total number of steps in chains to save.
thinSteps=1                   # Number of steps to "thin" (1=keep every step).
nPerChain = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains ) # Steps per chain.
# Create, initialize, and adapt the model:
jagsModel = jags.model( "model.txt" , data=datalist ,
                        n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
# Burn-in:
cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )
# The saved MCMC chain:
cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
codaSamples = coda.samples( jagsModel , variable.names=parameters ,
                            n.iter=nPerChain , thin=thinSteps )
mcmcChain = as.matrix( codaSamples )
chainLength = NROW(mcmcChain)

mu <- mcmcChain[, "mu"]
sig <-  mcmcChain[, "sig"]
L <- length(mu)

v <- numeric()
for( i in 1:L){
    yrep <- rlnorm(length(y),mu[i],sig[i])
    v[i] <- t(log(yrep),mu[i]) >= t(log(y),mu[i])
}

t <- function(dist,theta){
    abs(orderstat(dist,floor(length(dist)*0.90)) - theta) -
        abs(orderstat(dist,floor(length(dist)*0.10)) - theta)
}
orderstat <- function(x,pos){
    sort(x)[pos]
}
```

**Reference:**
2003 "Bayesian Data Analysis", Andrew Gelman et. al